# clear text box using JS function in a href on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function:

```
<script>
    function ClearTextBox(textbox_name) {
        $(textbox_name).val("")
    }
    </script>
```

that removes values from a text input

i am trying to call it using:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="ClearTextBox('#customercompany1')">Clear</a>
```

but its not clearing the text box

Comment: Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/T9U4u/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) .

Try this code.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
 $('#customercompany1').val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems working fine for me.. but the console shows the following error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

this is due to the `javascript:void();` in your `href` attribute.

so i changed the mark up to

```
<a href="#" onclick="return ClearTextBox('#customercompany1');">Clear</a>

<input type="text" id="customercompany1" value="test value" />
```

and the script as

```
function ClearTextBox(textboxname) {
        $(textboxname).val(" ");
         return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps....

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn9R3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Write your function like this:

```
   function ClearTextBox(myInput) {
        var txtBox = document.getElementById(myInput);
        txtBox.value = "";
        return false;
    }
```

And write your html like this:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return ClearTextBox('customercompany1');">Clear</a>
        <input type="text" id="customercompany1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to see your HTML to be sure, but I'm guessing your text box looks like this :

```
 <input type="text" name="customercompany1"/>
```

and it needs to look like this :

```
 <input type="text" name="customercompany1" id="customercompany1"/>
```

---

The '#' jQuery selector matches on the id attribute, not the name attribute.

(This is true if you have used a textarea rather than an input)